# Yii2 gridview filter with comparison operators

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to filter gridview results with a column greater than specified value?
My gridview have a column amount. When user searches as 1000, i want to filter results as amount greater than 1000. How do i do this?
Now my search model is like this.

```
public function search($params) {
            $query = Service::find();
            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => $query,
                'sort' => ['defaultOrder' => ['id' => SORT_DESC,
                    ]]
            ]);

            $this->load($params);

            if (!$this->validate()) {
                    // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
                    // $query->where('0=1');
                    return $dataProvider;
            }

            // grid filtering conditions
            $query->andFilterWhere([
                'id' => $this->id,
                'patient_id' => $this->patient_id,
                'service' => $this->service,
                'duty_type' => $this->duty_type,
                'staff_manager' => $this->staff_manager,
                'from_date' => $this->from_date,
                'to_date' => $this->to_date,
                'branch_id' => $this->branch_id,
                'status' => $this->status,
                'CB' => $this->CB,
                'UB' => $this->UB,
                'DOC' => $this->DOC,
                'DOU' => $this->DOU,
            ]);


            $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'estimated_price', $this->estimated_price])
                    ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'amount', $this->amount])
                    ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'days', $this->days])
                    ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'service_id', $this->service_id]);

            return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Comment: Change your query in `searchModel`.

Comment: Can you please show me a example?

Comment: You always want to compare greater than entered value?

Comment: Yes. How do i change my searchmodel to do that and my filed name is amount

Comment: add searchModel.

Comment: see my searchmodel in question. how do i change this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'estimated_price', $this->estimated_price])
     ->andFilterWhere(['>', 'amount', $this->amount])
     ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'days', $this->days])
     ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'service_id', $this->service_id]);
```

If you want to include entered amount in search result, use `>=`.

Comment: Shall i ask one more question. suppose the user want to search the amount greater than 1000 and also want to search amount less than 1000 or amount between 500 and 1000. Can i all do this by >,<,between for the same field?

Comment: @sabithavarghese yes, you can. But it also depends on type of output needed. Remember between requires four operands.